# How to rotate a box in-place

Tags: boxes, rotating

The following LaTeX code illustrates my question. Is it possible to get what I want without doing the negative `\hskip`, as I want a *simple* generic solution which will rotate the box to any angle (center origin) but leave it 'in-place'?

An ideal solution would allow me to do this:

```
{a}\somespecialrotate[origin=c]{\anyangle}{b}
```

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\bxa
\newsavebox\bxb
\huge
\savebox\bxa{\color{red}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}
\savebox\bxb{\color{black}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}
\usebox\bxa\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\usebox\bxb}This is what I do not want\par
\usebox\bxa\hskip-0.25cm\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\usebox\bxb}This is what I DO want
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The behaviour here is deliberate (and actually takes work at the low level). Do you want a 'higher-level' package solution or one that uses only `graphicx`?

Comment: If it can be done simply with the `graphicx` package, that would be good.

Comment: @Dan: I added now an alternative solution which only uses `graphicx`.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

This can be easily done with `adjustbox` v0.8 from `2011/11/14`. It provides the original width as `\Width` which can be used to center the rotated content around it (with the rest overlapping on the left and right) or to calculate the amount which the rotated content should overlap to the left, which is the `\hskip` you are talking about. The current width is always `\width`, so `lap=-.5\width+.5\Width` will make the rotated content lap over to the left. See the `adjustbox` manual for details.

With an older version of `adjustbox` you can substitute `\Width` with `\wd\bxb` if you box the content by yourself. If you don't want to use `adjustbox`, but rather do it yourself, you need to box both the original content (`\bxb`) and the rotated one (say `\bxc`) and then use `\mbox{\hskip\dimexpr -.5\wd\bxb+.5\wd\bxc\relax\usebox\bxc}` to typeset the box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}[2011/11/14]
\usepackage{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\newsavebox\bxa
\newsavebox\bxb
\huge
\savebox\bxa{\color{red}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}
\savebox\bxb{\color{black}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}
\usebox\bxa\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\usebox\bxb}This is what I do not want\par
\usebox\bxa\hskip-0.25cm\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\usebox\bxb}This is what I DO want

\usebox\bxa\adjustbox{origin=c,angle=45,center=\Width}{\usebox\bxb}This is with the original width

\usebox\bxa\adjustbox{origin=c,angle=45,lap=-.5\width+.5\Width}{\usebox\bxb}This is with overlapping only at the left

% As macro:
\newcommand{\somespecialrotate}[2][]{\adjustbox{#1,angle={#2},lap=-.5\width+.5\Width}}

\usebox\bxa\somespecialrotate[origin=c]{15}{\usebox\bxb}This is some text\par
\usebox\bxa\somespecialrotate[origin=c]{25}{\usebox\bxb}This is some text\par
\usebox\bxa\somespecialrotate[origin=c]{35}{\usebox\bxb}This is some text\par
\usebox\bxa\somespecialrotate[origin=c]{45}{\usebox\bxb}This is some text\par
\usebox\bxa\somespecialrotate[origin=c]{55}{\usebox\bxb}This is some text\par
\usebox\bxa\somespecialrotate[origin=c]{65}{\usebox\bxb}This is some text\par
\usebox\bxa\somespecialrotate[origin=c]{75}{\usebox\bxb}This is some text\par
\usebox\bxa\somespecialrotate[origin=c]{85}{\usebox\bxb}This is some text\par
\usebox\bxa\somespecialrotate[origin=c]{95}{\usebox\bxb}This is some text\par
\end{document}
```

---

Here a `graphicx`-only solution which only uses one temporary box register:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\somespecialrotate}[3][]{%
    \begingroup
    \sbox\@tempboxa{#3}%
    \@tempdima=.5\wd\@tempboxa
    \sbox\@tempboxa{\rotatebox[#1]{#2}{\usebox\@tempboxa}}%
    \advance\@tempdima by -.5\wd\@tempboxa
    \mbox{\hskip\@tempdima\usebox\@tempboxa}%
    \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\huge
{\color{red}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}\somespecialrotate[origin=c]{45}{\color{black}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}This is some text\par
{\color{red}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}\somespecialrotate[origin=c]{30}{\color{black}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}This is some text\par

\end{document}
```

---

[image: Result]

Lower part:

[image: Result2]

And here for angles from 0,5,...,180:

[image]

Comment: Show off! Great! :D

Comment: Reminds me of when they decided to put some Bach on the CD they sent out on Voyager - I think it was Carl Sagan who said it would be showing off! <:-) Bach was a compatriot of Martin's, ich denke.

Comment: little mistake in `\mbox{\hskip\dimexpr -.5\wd\bxb+.5\bxbc\relax\usebox\bxc}` ?? `\bxc` instead of `\bxbc` ?. but I'm not sure I try this method in my question http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46073/how-to-adjust-rotatebox-to-emulate-some-options-of-node-from-tikz but with no success

Answer (score 9):

use `\makebox` to get the same width without rotating:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newsavebox\bxa
\newsavebox\bxb
\makeatletter
\newcommand\somespecialrotate[3][]{%
  \sbox\bxa{#3}\makebox[\wd\bxa]{\rotatebox[#1]{#2}{#3}}}
\makeatother
\def\RotateBox#1#2{\sbox{\bxa}{#2}\sbox\bxb{\rotatebox[origin=c]{#1}{#2}}%
  \makebox[\wd\bxa]{\usebox\bxb}\kern\dimexpr(\wd\bxb-\wd\bxa)/2\relax}
\begin{document}
\huge
\color{red}\rule{1cm}{1cm}%
\rotatebox[origin=c]{45}{\color{black}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}This is what I do not want\par
\rule{1cm}{1cm}%
\RotateBox{45}{\color{black}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}This is what I DO want\par

\color{red}\rule{1cm}{1cm}%
\somespecialrotate[origin=c]{45}{\color{black}\rule{1cm}{1cm}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with that is the OP apparently wants the right side to keep is new size, so that the text is not printed on top of the rotated square. Here the 'T' of 'This' overlaps with it.

Comment: If I was not worried about the overlap on the right how could I create a macro which used this `\makebox` idea so I could do: {a}\somespecialrotate[origin=c]{\anyangle}{b}

I can't see why my attempt below does NOT work:

Comment: `\makeatletter\newcommand{\somespecialrotate}[3][]{\sbox\@tempboxa{#3}\makebox[\wd\@tempboxa]{\rotatebox[#1]{#2}{#3}}}\makeatother`

Comment: @Dan: see my edited answer, it has your macro.

Comment: Thank you. Is it my use of @tempboxa which causes it to fail?

Comment: @Dan: not your fault, it depends to the system which uses this value also internal and so it is overwritten