# How to emulate some options of \node from TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, programming

[image]

**Code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture} 
  \foreach \a in {0,45,...,315}%
   {\node[line width = 0pt,
          rotate     = \a,
          anchor     = west,
          inner sep  = 0pt,
          opacity    = .5]{\rule{.5cm}{.1cm}};}%      
\end{tikzpicture}    
\end{document}
```

I would to get the same result with `\rotatebox` and `\put` but **other interesting methods are allowed without TikZ**.

Some explanations of the first code :

1. `anchor     = west` is the most important  if we want to place the rules at the same point
2. `inner sep  = 0pt` to remove white space around the rule (> 0pt -> pretty pictures)
3. `line width = 0p` subtlety! without this a small white point appears at the center
4. `opacity    = .5` only to watch how the rules are placed.

**First try**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} % I keep TikZ because `foreach` is useful  
 \begin{document}

 \begin{picture}(0,0)
       \foreach \a in {0,45,...,315}%
      {\put(0,0){\rotatebox[origin=l]{\a}{\mbox{\rule{.5cm}{.1cm}}}}}%    
 \end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It's normal because the boxes are misplaced, we can see why if we remove `put`:

[image]

I'm a serious guy so  I found  [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35143/how-to-rotate-box-in-place) and some good and useful answers so ...

**Second try**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\somespecialrotate}[3][]{%
    \begingroup
    \sbox\@tempboxa{\rotatebox[#1]{#2}{#3}}%
    \@tempdima=-\wd\@tempboxa 
    \advance\@tempdima by 0.09cm  % this is one of the problem
    \mbox{\hskip\@tempdima\usebox\@tempboxa}%
    \endgroup}%
\makeatother    
\begin{document}      
\begin{picture}(0,0)
       \foreach \a in {-90,-45,...,90}%
      {\put(0,0){\rotatebox[origin=l]{\a}{\mbox{\rule{.5cm}{.1cm}}}}}%  
       \put(0,0){\somespecialrotate[origin=l]{180}{\mbox{\rule{.5cm}{.1cm}}}}% 
       \put(0,0){\somespecialrotate[origin=l]{135}{\mbox{\rule{.5cm}{.1cm}}}}%
       \put(0,0){\somespecialrotate[origin=l]{225}{\mbox{\rule{.5cm}{.1cm}}}}%     
 \end{picture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This looks fine but `\advance\@tempdima by 0.09cm` is not serious and if I compare with the first code

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\somespecialrotate}[3][]{%
    \begingroup
    \sbox\@tempboxa{\rotatebox[#1]{#2}{#3}}%
    \@tempdima=-\wd\@tempboxa 
    \advance\@tempdima by 0.09cm  % this is one of the problem
    \mbox{\hskip\@tempdima\usebox\@tempboxa}%
    \endgroup}%
\makeatother    
\begin{document}  
\begin{picture}(0,0)
       \foreach \a in {-90,-45,...,90}%
      {\put(0,0){\rotatebox[origin=l]{\a}{\mbox{\rule{.5cm}{.1cm}}}}}%  
       \put(0,0){\somespecialrotate[origin=l]{180}{\mbox{\rule{.5cm}{.1cm}}}}% 
       \put(0,0){\somespecialrotate[origin=l]{135}{\mbox{\rule{.5cm}{.1cm}}}}%
       \put(0,0){\somespecialrotate[origin=l]{225}{\mbox{\rule{.5cm}{.1cm}}}}%     
 \end{picture}%
\color{red}%
\begin{tikzpicture} [overlay]
\foreach \a in {0,45,...,315}%
   {\node[rotate=\a,anchor=west,inner sep=0pt,opacity=.5]{\rule{.5cm}{.1cm}};}%      
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

**My question**   How to get the same picture with `put`and `rotatebox`?

Comment: `pgffor` package is the one responsible for the `\foreach` goodies. So you can skip TikZ and load only `pgffor` package.

Comment: @percusse I agree with you and you are right. I know but I needed TikZ in the first and the last pictures so I keep TikZ for all the examples. But TikZ is not really the problem and I think the examples show how useful is this package.

Comment: No problem at all. It was just a minor reminder for the record.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non-tikz attempt to a solution (but keeping the `\foreach` for convenience).

First of all it is better to utilize an empty framed box, as is easier to visualize.

For this I would use an `\fbox` with the `fboxsep`, providing some empty padding. We will also use the rotating `package`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor} % I keep TikZ because `foreach` is useful  
\usepackage{rotating}
\fboxsep10pt
\def\transparentbox{\fbox{\hbox to 3cm{}}}
\parindent0pt
\begin{document}
\foreach \a in {0,45,...,315}{%
\turnbox{\a}{\transparentbox}}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But `\usepackage{picture}` is not useful here, isn't it ?

Comment: I can forget `\rotatebox`:) and like percusse wrote in an initial comment `\usepackage{pgffor}` is enough

Comment: @Altermundus Updated as per your comments and took all redundant packages out.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is very useful. I can now complete the examples for my new package pgfornament (it's like psvectorian but for pgf with more options). A last remark : you forgot to update the picture !

Comment: @Altermundus Good luck with the package, glad I could help. Updated the image as well.

Answer (score 3):

Partial answer because I get some other problems. I try this code proposed by  Martin 
`\mbox{\hskip\dimexpr -.5\wd\bxb+.5\bxc\relax\usebox\bxc}` but I get two problems. The first I introduce something wrong because the result is very bad but if I use the classical method

```
\@tempdima=\wd\bxb 
\advance\@tempdima by -\wd\bxc  % this is one of the problem 
\@tempdima=-0.5\@tempdima 
\mbox{\hskip\@tempdima\usebox\bxc}%
```

**Update** with the help of Werner to use Martin's suggestion. `dimexpr' is very useful.
Now I need to reduce this code (three loops with three different macros.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{tikz} 
\makeatletter 
\newbox\bxb
\newbox\bxc
\newcommand{\somespecialrotate}[3][]{%
\begingroup
    \sbox\bxb{#3}
    \sbox\bxc{\rotatebox[#1]{#2}{#3}}%
    \mbox{\hskip\dimexpr -.5\wd\bxb+.5\wd\bxc\relax\usebox\bxc}
\endgroup}% 
\newcommand{\somespecialrotatei}[3][]{%
\begingroup
    \sbox\bxb{#3}
    \sbox\bxc{\rotatebox[#1]{#2}{#3}}%
    \mbox{\hskip\dimexpr 0.5\wd\bxb-1.5\wd\bxc\relax\usebox\bxc}
\endgroup}%
\newcommand{\somespecialrotateii}[3][]{%
\begingroup
    \sbox\bxb{#3}
    \sbox\bxc{\rotatebox[#1]{#2}{#3}}%
    \mbox{\hskip\dimexpr -0.5\wd\bxc\relax\usebox\bxc}  
\endgroup}%   
\makeatother    
\begin{document} 

 \setlength{\fboxsep}{0pt}  
\begin{picture}(0,0)
       \foreach \a in {-45,0,45}%
      {\put(0,0){%
      \somespecialrotate[origin=l]{\a}{%
             \tikz \node[minimum width =2cm,%
                         minimum height=4mm,%
                         inner sep =0pt,draw,%
                         line width=.4pt]{};%
}}}%      
       \foreach \a in {135,180,225}%
      {\put(0,0){%
      \somespecialrotatei[origin=l]{\a}{%
             \tikz \node[minimum width =2cm,%
                         minimum height=4mm,%
                         inner sep =0pt,draw,%
                         line width=.4pt]{};%
}}}%
       \foreach \a in {90,-90}%
      {\put(0,0){%
      \somespecialrotateii[origin=l]{\a}{%
             \tikz \node[minimum width =2cm,%
                         minimum height=4mm,%
                         inner sep =0pt,draw,%
                         line width=.4pt]{};%
}}}%     
 \end{picture}%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Whenever you use a box in your `\dimexpr`, you need to reference a measure (like `\wd` or `\ht` or `\dp`). So, you would need `\mbox{\hskip\dimexpr -.5\wd\bxb+.5\wd\bxc\relax\usebox\bxc}`.

Comment: @Werner Thanks  I see the problem of syntax in the martin'code but I introduce a new one :( Now i would be happy if I can remove the three `foreach`and the three `somespecialrotate` . It's really ugly !

Comment: @Altermundus Please use `\usepackage{picture}` to use `dimexpr` and simplify the code.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Yes I will update my answer but can you explain what are the advantages to use `\usepackage{picture}`. I never used this package.

Comment: @Altermundus It's a package by Heiko Oberdiek, it enables you to do calculations, but see my answer below first. I am not very familiar with TikZ let me know if my answer is what you are after.

Comment: @YiannisLazarides Very fine you can update your answer with `\usepackage{pgffor}` instead of `\usepackage{tikz}` and for the loop with `\foreach \a in {0,45,...,315}{% ` you get exactly what I want.